# How can i optimize the query with $unwind as it first stage?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema that looks something like below..

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5a4d28ae4f46990ebfd773dc"),
        "student_id" : 0,
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : -146.09163691278604
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 99.41521018793881
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 0.002307340920915113
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 73.32279648314594
                }
        ],
        "class_id" : 143
}
```

Now i need to find the Highest Average a class_id has in type "exam" and who all students in that class got marks higher than calculated average in that particular class. I wrote something like below

```
db.students.aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$scores'
        }, {
            $match: {
                'scores.type': 'exam'
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$class_id',
                'average': {
                    $avg: '$scores.score'
                },
                'stud': {
                    $push: {
                        'student_id': '$student_id',
                        'marks': '$scores.score'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: {
                'average': -1
            }
        }, {
            $limit: 1
        }, {
            $project: {
                'Average Marks': '$average',
                'students_higher': {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$stud',
                        as: 'st',
                        cond: {
                            $gt: ['$$st.marks', '$average']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: '$students_higher'
        }, {
            $sort: {
                'students_higher.marks': -1
            }
        }
    ]).pretty()
```

However, the query usually takes around 900+ ms ~ 1sec on an average, i have pasted the most recent execution below (takes like 700ms, this is after i ran this query for 15+ times) and now its performance is haunting me. I know that $match should be first stage as part of best practices to leverage indexing but here i could not figure out anyway to optimize this, maybe some suggestions could help me.

```
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined: 0 docsExamined: 99998 hasSortStage: 1 cursorExhausted: 1 numYields: 785 nreturned: 97 reslen: 9972 locks: {
    Global: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 1632
        }
    },
    Database: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 816
        }
    },
    Collection: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 816
        }
    }
}
protocol: op_msg 788ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below option, it takes out $unwind and $match, instead it is using a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with a [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

```
db.so.aggregate([ 
{$project:{
  _id:1,
  student_id:1,
  class_id:1,
  scores:{
    $filter:{
      input:"$scores",
      as:"scores",
      cond:{$eq:["$$scores.type", "exam"]} 
    }
  }
 }}, 
 { $group: {
     _id: '$class_id',
     'average': {
          $avg: '$scores.score'
     },
     'stud': { 
          $push: {
             'student_id': '$student_id', 
             'marks': '$scores.score' 
          }
      }
 }},
{ $sort: { 'average': -1 }},
{ $limit: 1 },
{ $project: { 
     'Average Marks': '$average', 
     'students_higher': { 
          $filter: { 
              input: '$stud', 
              as: 'st',   
              cond: { $gt: ['$$st.marks', '$average']} 
          }   
      }
 }},
 { $unwind: '$students_higher' },
 { $sort: { 'students_higher.marks': -1 }}
]).pretty()
```

Please note if the document

```
scores:[
  {
    "type" : "exam",
    "score" : -146.09163691278604
  },
  ....
]
```

is always having the `type:exam` document in the first position in the array of `scores` then $project with $slice would be more faster

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a preliminary $match stage to the pipeline to potentially filter out any students who never took an exam. This will reduce the number of documents that need to be unbound.

As an added benefit, this will allow the aggregation to utilize the index `{ "scores.type" : 1 }` once it is created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did that earlier but as it would be a an index on array, probably the right mongodb term - multikeyIndex, it would go through many Keys more than the actual documents in collection and performance gets down drastically sometimes taking 1.2seconds, if you wish i can post the results

Comment: Also, there are only 2 records where exam type score are not present.